# SQLite query in Android does not return correct values

Tags: android, sqlite

The following query does not return a value for sellingprice even though it is in the database. It returns a value for all other fields, except sellingprice.

```
SELECT itemid, unitid, itemdesc, unitdescription, case ? when 1 then sellingprice1 when 2 then sellingprice2 when 3 then sellingprice3 when 4 then sellingprice4 when 5 then sellingprice5 end sellingprice FROM ITEMS WHERE COMPANYID = ? ORDER BY ITEMDESC, UNITDESCRIPTION
```

If I substitute the ? with 2 and 7, then it returns a value for the sellingrice

```
SELECT itemid, unitid, itemdesc, unitdescription, case 2 when 1 then sellingprice1 when 2 then sellingprice2 when 3 then sellingprice3 when 4 then sellingprice4 when 5 then sellingprice5 end sellingprice FROM ITEMS WHERE COMPANYID = 7 ORDER BY ITEMDESC, UNITDESCRIPTION
```

Here is how I execute the query

```
cursor = dbContext.rawQuery(query, new String[] {Integer.toString(priceLevel), Integer.toString(companyId)});
```

And here is how I traverse the returned cursor

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Log.i("item desc", cursor.getString(2));
            Log.i("sellingprice", Double.toString(cursor.getDouble(4)));

            items.add(new ItemDisplay(cursor.getInt(0), 
                                        cursor.getInt(1),
                                        cursor.getString(2),
                                        cursor.getString(3),
                                        cursor.getDouble(4)));

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It turns out, RAWQUERY only uses parameters for its WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

`rawQuery()` supports only strings as parameters, and the string `'2'` does not match the number `2`.

The `companyId` comparison might work if the table column has numeric [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity), but in Android, it is a better idea to use parameters only for actual string values.

Comment: How do you execute a query that requires a numeric parameter?

Comment: You don't use parameters; just `"... WHERE x = " + integer + "..."`.